# How to use Content Resolver to query SQLite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-database

Currently i'm using `db.query()` method to access database directly and code is running perfectly. But when i try to use Content Resolver to access database using `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query()` method, the app doesn't start. I have created Contract class to store constant and CustomerProvider Class to use as `ContentProvider`.

CatalogActivity (mainActivity):

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private CustomerDbHelper mdbHelper;
Button addbutton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

    addbutton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, AddCustomerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    mdbHelper=new CustomerDbHelper(this);
    displayDatabaseInfo();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    displayDatabaseInfo();
}

protected void displayDatabaseInfo(){
    CustomerDbHelper mdbHelper=new CustomerDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=mdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection={CustomerEntry._ID,
            CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_NAME,
            CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS,
            CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PHONE };


    // Cursor cursor = db.query(CustomerEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null);//when i use this command code runs perfectly
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            CustomerEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null); // i want to use this method but here problem occur,App doesn't stars.


    try {
        TextView  TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TV1.setText("NUMBER OF ROWS= " + cursor.getCount());
        TV1.append("\n"+"currentId-currentname-currentaddress-cureentphone");
        int idColumnIndex=cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerEntry._ID);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_NAME);
        int addressColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS);
        int phoneColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerEntry.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PHONE);

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
             int  currentId=cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
             String currentname = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
             String currentaddress = cursor.getString(addressColumnIndex);
             int currentphone = cursor.getInt(phoneColumnIndex);

            TV1.append("\n"+currentId+"-"+currentname+"-"+currentaddress+"-"+currentphone);

        }

    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

CutomerContract (contract class):

```
public final class CustomerContract {
private CustomerContract() {
}

public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.try1";
public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_AUTHORITY = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
public static final String PATH_CUSTOMER_TABLE = "customer";

public static final class CustomerEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_AUTHORITY, PATH_CUSTOMER_TABLE);

    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "customer";
    public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_NAME = "name";
    public final static String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = "address";
    public final static String COLUMN_CUSTOMER_PHONE = "phone";
}

}
```

CustomerProvider (Contentprovider) Class

```
public class CustomerProvider extends ContentProvider {
private CustomerDbHelper mDbHelper;
private static final int CUSTOMER = 100;
private static final int CUSTOMER_ID =101;
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sUriMatcher.addURI(CustomerContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,CustomerContract.PATH_CUSTOMER_TABLE,CUSTOMER);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(CustomerContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,CustomerContract.PATH_CUSTOMER_TABLE  + "/#",CUSTOMER_ID);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDbHelper=new CustomerDbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (match){
        case CUSTOMER:
            cursor = database.query(CustomerEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null, null, sortOrder);
            break;

        case CUSTOMER_ID:
            selection = CustomerEntry._ID + "=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
            cursor = database.query(CustomerEntry.TABLE_NAME, projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot query unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    return cursor;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable ContentValues contentValues, @Nullable String s, @Nullable String[] strings) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

**Logcat is showing following message:**

```
 09-15 02:55:02.768 3391-3391/com.example.android.try1 E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.example.android.try1
09-15 02:55:02.768 3391-3391/com.example.android.try1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-15 02:55:02.769 3391-3391/com.example.android.try1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.android.try1, PID: 3391
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.try1/com.example.android.try1.CatalogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.database.Cursor.close()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.database.Cursor.close()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.example.android.try1.CatalogActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(CatalogActivity.java:91)
                                                                            at com.example.android.try1.CatalogActivity.onCreate(CatalogActivity.java:40)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Did you add "<provider>" node for your provider in Manifest?

Comment: Yes i have added <provider/> node in manifest.xml file.

Comment: catalog showing following msg: